# invert the mouse movements from a joystick programmatically using C#, NET 40+,and WPF

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, joystick

I need to invert the mouse movements from a joystick movement.

I am developing on Win 10 for Win 7. I am using Visual Studio 2015, C#, WPF.

I have tried OnSourceInitialized/HwndSourceHook and the MouseHook class but neither one seems to hook WM_MOUSEMOVE messages. In addition, I would like to not just only hook these messages but invert them.

Can anyone please help with observations and solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you receiving joystick events?  They're definitely not going to come through as mouse events.

Comment: Overriding OnSourceInitialized looking for WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Comment: Why would a joystick send mouse messages?  It’s not a pointing device and doesn’t behave like one.

Comment: I believe joystick movement messages should come in as [MM_JOY1MOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743687).

Comment: Why would a joystick send mouse messages?

Comment: Why would a joystick send mouse messages? Because the manufacturer specifies that the joystick functions like a mouse. Would Windows differentiate and respond accordingly?